# Adding external JAR to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jar, buildpath

I am using the spring frame work tutorial, I am in the part I have to add the external JAR  but I seem to be missing some like org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M2, antlr-runtime-3.0.1. SO what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Download those dependent jar files.

```
Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Add External Jars
```

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_java_build_path.htm) to setup java build path in eclipse.

[image: Managing Java Build Path]

Comment: you're the best

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all, download that jar from this link:

```
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadantlrruntime301jar.htm
```

and then Right click on your project and Goto BUIld path and select ADD External Jar.

```
Right Click -> Build path -> add externalJars
```

and even you can add it into the /WEB-INF/lib folder too.

and that way program will work error will be solved.